# Swift: Combine two or more regular expressions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, nsregularexpression

I'm using two regular expressions:

```
    var myNumbers  = numbers.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)


myNumbers  = myNumbers?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^\\s*$", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)
```

I'm removing non number characters and spaces but there a way to combine the regular expressions ?

Comment: The second regex will never match anything unless the string contains exclusively whitespace characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var myNumbers  = numbers.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[\\s\\D]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Code's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950341/3141234), the `\s` token captures all white space (tabs, spaces, new lines, etc.), and `\D` captures all digits.

```
let regex = "[\\s\\D]"

var myNumbers  = numbers.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(regex,
                                                         withString: "",
                                                            options: .RegularExpressionSearch,
                                                              range: nil)
```

Swift has automatic enum inference, so you don't need to write `NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch`. You can just write `.RegularExpressionSearch`, and the `NSStringCompareOptions` will be infered by the compiler from the signature of the function.